# How to change some value in .java file from build.gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have situation where I have multiple flavors of my app. For ex.
Dev, Stage, Production flavors.

So, dev will be pointing to dev server url, dev app id etc. and same for stage and production.
For app id which are present in my strings.xml, I can replace them using following code -

```
variant.mergeResources.doLast {
        File valuesFile = file("${buildDir}/res/all/${variant.dirName}/values/values.xml")
        println("Replacing app id in " + variant.dirName)
        String content = valuesFile.getText('UTF-8')
        def appid;
        String variantDirName = variant.dirName;
        if (variantDirName.contains("dev")) {
            appid = '1234_dev'
        } else if(variantDirName.contains("stage")) {
            appid = '1234_stage'
        } else if(variantDirName.contains("prod")) {
            appid = '1234_prod'
        } else {
            appid = '1234_unknown'
        }
        content = content.replaceAll(/some_app_id/, appid)
        valuesFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
    }
```

where my strings.xml is -

```
    <string name="app_id">some_app_id</string>
```

Now, server urls are stored in my Config.java file as normal constant-

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://dev.blahblah.com";
```

So the question is how to change this line in Config.java from my build.gradle file depending upon different flavor?

Comment: Why not a property file with the appropriate name which you'd read from? You can do that from a static initializer

Comment: How to tell my Config.java that use url from property file? Can u post answer using your approach? It seems a good way. Just its more better if you illustrate using example.  Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you get that app_id, too. I don't know android...

Comment: If I keep url in strings.xml. Anyone can extract my .apk file and read strings.xml so I dont want to go with that approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't edit the output of existing tasks like this, this is going to break incremental support and every time you build, it'll rerun the mergeResource task (because its output were changed).

In this case I'd simply use `resConfig` and `buildConfigField` to dynamically create a res and a constant field in `BuildConfig`

Comment: Thanks. I just found somewhere on the web. This is the perfect approach I think.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more information that more specifically explains:1. The original question, how do you actually change a value in a java file? 2. How do you use a constant that was created in buildConfigField? I cannot find any documentation on that. Thanks!

Comment: buildConfigField will create a new constant in the generated class `<your package Name>.BuildConfig`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use BuildConfig as Xavier sad. Example:

In product flavors

```
productFlavors {
    develop {
        applicationId "com.dexode.cree.develop"
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false

        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.test.dexode.com/2.3\""
    }
    beta {
        applicationId "com.dexode.cree.beta"
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true

        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.dexode.com/2.3\""
    }
    production {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.dexode.com/2.3\""
    }
```

So now your BuildConfig looks like:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.dexode.cree.develop.debug";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "develop";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0.0_debug";
  // Fields from product flavor: develop
  public static final String API_URL = "https://api.test.dexode.com/2.3";
}
```

And usage in code:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BuildConfig.API_URL);
```

Remember to refresh content of file BuildConfig. AndroidStudio like to cache files. You can click File -> Synchronize

[Documentation about Flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)

Related question [buildConfigField depending on flavor + buildType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506290/buildconfigfield-depending-on-flavor-buildtype)