# buildConfigField depending on flavor + buildType

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I'm trying to define a *buildConfigVariable* depending on the *flavor* + *buildType*. Ideally, this is what I want

```
productFlavors {
    strawberry {
        buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", name + variant.buildType.name
    }
    ... more flavors ..
}
```

*name* does contain "strawberry", but I don't know if it's possible to access the *variant*'s *buildType*.

Placed outside the *Android* closure I do have access to the *BuildType* and *variant*, but then I can't invoke `buildConfigField`

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "flavor: ${variant.flavorName}"
    println "****************************"

    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
        if (variant.flavorName == 'strawberry') {
            buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", '"strawberry_release"'
        } else {
            buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", '"chocolate_release"'
        }
    } else if(variant.buildType.name == 'debug') {
        if (variant.flavorName == 'strawberry') {
            buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", '"strawberry_debug"'
        } else {
            buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", '"chocolate_debug"'
        }
    }


****************************
variant: strawberryRelease
flavor: strawberry
****************************
org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: 
    Could not find method buildConfigField() 
    for arguments [String, WS_API_KEY, "strawberry_release"]
```

I can easily create a Java factory and return the appropriate `API_KEY` depending on some `BuildConfig` constants, but I'd rather keep the code configuration agnostic.

Comment: In addition: [How to add buildConfigField to individual productFlavors?](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112378857970945433614/posts/DoNedk9Vq2e)

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983681/3333878

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit2: The version after 0.14.2 will allow doing this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.buildConfigField "int", "VALUE", "1"
}
```

So you'd be able to do something like this (to match the original question):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.buildConfigField "String", "WS_API_KEY", variant.productFlavors.get(0).name + '_' + variant.buildType.name
}
```

<strike>Edit: it's not currently possible. The API is missing for this.
Bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67416</strike>

Try this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergedFlavor.buildConfigField "String", "NAME", '"VALUE"'
}
```

Comment: That throws an error MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.android.builder.DefaultProductFlavor.buildConfigField() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [String, NAME, "VALUE"]
  Possible solutions: getBuildConfigFields()

Comment: I have a solution of my own tho it's probably fragile, so I'd be happy to see a better one. I'll post it in 5 minutes.

Comment: oh yeah, mergedFlavor is not of the proper type for this. let me look.

Comment: Hi Xavier, I've updated my answer with a working version, but I'm curious if there's a better way (there must be, I guess). Thanks for your work!

Comment: well this looks quite ugly, but I guess there's no better way right now. We'll have to improve this. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67416

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on that bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: this might be a fragile solution, use at your own risk. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67416**

This is how I accomplished what I wanted. You need to change the values just before the task is executed, so I needed a way to hook my code in there.

```
final projectName = project.name
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
    if (task.path ==~ /:$projectName:generate.*BuildConfig/) {
        //extracts flavor and buildType name. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7594052/218473 for regex
        final values = task.name.replace("generate","").replace("BuildConfig","").split("(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")

        final flavorName = values[0].toLowerCase()
        final buildTypeName = values[1].toLowerCase()

        com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant;
        android.applicationVariants.all { currentVariant ->
            if (currentVariant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getBuildType().getName() == buildTypeName) {
                if (currentVariant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName() == flavorName) {
                    variant = currentVariant;
                }
            }
        }

        if(variant != null) {
            com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl apiKeyField
            if (flavorName == 'strawberry') {    
                if (buildTypeName == 'release') {
                    apiKeyField = new com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl("String", "WS_API_KEY", '"strawberry_release"')
                } else {
                    apiKeyField = new com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl("String", "WS_API_KEY", '"strawberry_debug"')
                }
            } else if (flavorName == 'chocolate') {                        
                if (buildTypeName == 'release') {
                    apiKeyField = new com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl("String", "WS_API_KEY", '"chocolate_release"')
                } else {
                    apiKeyField = new com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl("String", "WS_API_KEY", '"chocolate_debug"')
                }
            }

            variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorConfigs().get(0).addBuildConfigField(apiKeyField)
        }
    }
}
```

To understand why this works, download the AOSP source code and check *VariantConfiguration.getBuildConfigItems()*

Using Xavier's answer throws a MethodMissingError. If I use *variant.mergedFlavor.addBuildConfigField()* there's no error, but the variable isn't added.

Comment: You can use the public API, no need for `ClassFieldImpl`: `com.android.builder.model.ClassField apiKeyField` and then declare `def createClassField = com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.&createClassField` and then instead of calling `new ClassFieldImpl(...)` you can just call `createClassField(...)`.