# How to properly set multiple applicationIds or package names in my manifests

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-manifest, build.gradle

I have an issue that is directly related to this question: [How to have two build flavors inherit from a root flavor in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636282/how-to-have-two-build-flavors-inherit-from-a-root-flavor-in-android-studio/26637371?noredirect=1#comment44814977_26637371) but it makes sense to pull it out into another question. I have this in my build.gradle:

```
flavorGroups 'fruit', 'paid'

productFlavors {
    apple {
        flavorGroup 'fruit'
    }
    orange {
        flavorGroup 'fruit'
    }
    free {
        flavorGroup 'paid'
    }
    premium {
        flavorGroup 'paid'
    }
}
```

I have four unique applications at this point.

1. Apple Free
2. Apple Paid
3. Orange Free
4. Orange Paid

But they do not have unique package names/application ids just yet.

How do I set up four unique app ids/package names in this situation?

---

**What I've tried?**

In the previous question @Scott Barta suggested just to set the package names in the manifest for each of the four application.

When I tried creating four additional manifests (Note: I had my single "core" manifest before in /main) I got an error: Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared. It seems as though I removed the package name from the core manifest file (in /main) it doesn't want to build.

Comment: "Does this mean I need a package in my main/manifest?" -- my guess is that it means that you need your `orange` manifests with their `package` attributes. BTW, use `flavorDimension`, not `flavorGroup`, on current versions of the Gradle for Android plugin.

Comment: I'll try that now. And yes, I know about flavorDimension, I just haven't upgraded to Android Studio 1.0 yet with the newest plugin(s)

Comment: @CommonsWare added packages to orange manifests. Now back at the error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:processAppleFreeDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared`

Comment: Per the "instructions" of the error message. I added a package in main/manifest and I get the error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:processAppleFreeDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5 value=(com.myapp.applefree)
   has a different value=(this.shouldnt.matter) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5 
   Suggestion : remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml  and place it in the build.gradle:
    flavorName {
     applicationId = "com.myapp.applefree"
    }`

Comment: Can you rework your question to be more clear about what you want and what things you've tried? I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @ScottBarta rephrased the question. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to customize the `applicationId` is to use [Gradle's `applicationIdSuffix` property](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-how-to-have-multiple-app-dev-versions-on-your-devices). Example below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example'
}

flavorGroups 'fruit', 'paid'

productFlavors {
    apple {
        flavorGroup 'fruit'
        applicationIdSuffix '.apple'
    }
    orange {
        flavorGroup 'fruit'
        applicationIdSuffix '.orange'
    }
    free {
        flavorGroup 'paid'
        applicationIdSuffix '.free'
    }
    premium {
        flavorGroup 'paid'
        applicationIdSuffix '.premium'
    }
}
```

Gradle has a full-featured programming language, Groovy, built in, so you can do more [elaborate voodoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26628240/40352) than this, but this is the easiest way.