# How to create packages in Android Studio for different gradle flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I am new to android programming. I just released my app. All works well and everything. However I was thinking of making a new **flavor (free)** **version** of the app by using the **flavor** feature of **gradle**.

Now all the tutorials and example of flavors that i see tell about storing exclusive classes of different **flavors** separate, for instance

**com.example.myapp.free**

**com.example.myapp.paid**

and keep the common files in main. Now my issue is, since i have already released the app, I cannot change the package name of my app to the .paid name as mentioned above. However my free version will implement the same class with different logic. If I do this, I get the **duplicate class:com**... error

How do i get around this situation?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636282/how-to-have-two-build-flavors-inherit-from-a-root-flavor-in-android-studio

Comment: Thank you for the link, however it doesn't solve my problem. They already have separate flavors established. My paid app is already released and I am asking how I would avoid duplicate without changing package names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

defined gradle config like this:

```
    productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.blah.blah.free"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId "com.blah.blah"
    }
```

This allowed me to keep the release package same, and at the same time, I added learned the hard way to design and modularize app properly. I had make copies of my activity classes in both flavors and delete from main. Resource overriding automatically handles everything except the classes.