# Resolve Application label for each build type

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I want to resolve manifestPlaceholders dependency for each build types and flavors. For example, I have

```
 productFlavors {
        dev {
            manifestPlaceholders = ['applicationLabel': 'DevFlavor']
        }

        prod {
            manifestPlaceholders = ['applicationLabel': 'ProdFlavor']
        }
.....

 buildTypes {
        debug {
            def old_name = manifestPlaceholders.get('applicationLabel'); // every time is null
//            def old_name = productFlavors.dev.manifestPlaceholders.get('applicationLabel');  // ITS OK, but not dynamic 
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: old_name + ' Dev']
        }
```

Is the any solution to add 'Dev' suffix to debug product flavors?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you want to adjust the application's label for each flavor / build type, there is maybe a better way to do it, via resValue / buildConfig fields, e.g. set a resValue string to `app_name`, alter it in applicationVariants.all, and use it in your manifest as application label. Does this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506290/buildconfigfield-depending-on-flavor-buildtype provide some help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just to give a working example to my comment above:

1. declare a `resValue` in your `defaultConfig` which will become the Application's name. (**Attention:** if you choose to name it `app_name`, be sure to delete the original `app_name` property from your `strings.xml` file, or it will clash.)

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       // applicationId, versionCode, etc.

       (...)

       // define your base Applications name here
       resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'MyApp'
   }
   ```
2. set your `productFlavors` as you did already. You can leave them empty if it is ok for you to concat your App's name with the flavor's name only, or provide an explicit `resValue`, which will override the value from `defaultConfig`.

   ```
   productFlavors {
       dev {
           // resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'MyAppDevFlavor'
       }

       prod {
           // resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'MyAppProdFlavor'
       }
   }
   ```
3. configure the `resValue`'s name at gradle configuration time

   ```
   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       // get app_name field from defaultConfig
       def appName = variant.mergedFlavor.resValues.get('app_name').getValue()

       // concat new App name with each flavor's name
       appName = "${appName}"
       variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
           appName += " ${flavor.name}"
       }

       // optionally add buildType name
       appName += " ${variant.buildType.name}"

       // your requirement: if buildType == debug, add DEV to App name
       if(variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
           appName += " DEV"
       }

       // set new resVale
       variant.resValue 'string', 'app_name', appName
   }
   ```
4. In your AndroidManifest, set the `app_name` field:

   ```
   <application
       ...
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       ...
       >
   ```

As I mentioned above, be sure to delete the default `app_name` property from `strings.xml`

Comment: When do you run the renaming logic? I'm logging it and it runs, I can see the modified name, but the apk always has the original name. I've put it in the defaultConfig section.