# App name comes from obscure source

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-resources

I can't figure out the source for my app's name.

I have the typical `app_name` string, used for `Application`'s label and `MainActivity`'s label. For what I know this is the only source for the app's name and label on the launcher.

I had a "Old App Name", which I changed to "New App Name", but this edit is not reflected on the device. I checked the generated resources in `build/intermediates` and it says "New App Name".
At one point in the development I tried using `gradle` to generate the resource `app_name` following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092665/resolve-application-label-for-each-build-type/32220436#32220436), it didn't work (I guess the cause is the same).

I performed a search in the entire project, no "Old App Name" string came up.

I thought of a system cache on my devices that holds up to the hold name, so I created a new device in Genymotion. Still "Old App Name".

Where should I look?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<string name="app_name">New App Name</string>
```

Comment: go to `app setting and clear cache`. may be solve your issue

Comment: On the device? I uninstalled it, cleared caches, nuked it with all i got. Then I made a new emulator in genymotion, just to be sure. Still "Old App Name".

Comment: Found the problem.... a translation of the old string, not updated with the new one. Now I just need to understand how it was created.

Comment: god damn men such a silly mistake can take long hours.

Comment: Yep, with 30+ values folders it's easy to miss something.

Answer (score 1):

app_name could be used by a library you are using and mistakenly being populated from there.

Create a new field for the apps name and use that instead to avoid the issue entirely e.g

```
<string name="My_unique_app_name">New App Name</string>
```

Comment: This didn't help. Also, the name I'm seeing now is the old one I used, not something from a library.